# Unable to vertically center Bootstrap 3 media

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center a Bootstrap 3 image Media object on the left side of a row. I am thus using pull-left to make CSS float the image to the left, but I am unable to center this image within the row itself despite trying all the recommended strategies online.

Here is a code snippet of what I am talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/afoxprogramming/aq9Laaew/242135/

Is it possible to vertically center those placeholder images within their row such that there is space above and below the images whose height is not the same as the text in their respective row? Below is some of the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/157x20"style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
      <p class=""><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
      <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p class=""><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the relevant CSS:

```
.index-page-list-image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove align-items: flex-start; and add following and you're done...

```
.media {
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `align-items: center;` 
so better create new class and apply it instead `media` class

```
.media-center{
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjt42xqc/)

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.index-page-list-image {
  width: 100%;
}
.media-center{
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media media-center">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/157x20"style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media media-center">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media media-center">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/57x35" style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the css of class class `.media` from `align-items: flex-start` to `align-items: center`, will fix the issue. please have a look at the below working snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  .row {
    background: #f8f9fa;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .media {
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .index-page-list-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/157x20" style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p class=""><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text.
          Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text.
          Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p class=""><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text.
          Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text.
          Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="media">
      <img class="pull-left img-responsive index-page-list-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/57x35" style="max-width: 33.33%">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p class=""><strong>Volunteering</strong></p>
        <p>Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text.
          Test text. Test text. est text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text. est text. Test text.
          Test text. Test text. Test text. Test text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```